# Do gender differences affect language learning strategies?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request

As far as I know, there have been many discussions and a considerable amount of research about differences in learning between boys and girls, or men and women. See for example:

- [Gender differences in the learning and teaching of surgery: a literature review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4207172/), by Carmen Mesas Burgos and Anna Josephson (2014),
- [Gender Differences in Learning and Achievement in Mathematics, Science, and Technology and Strategies for Equity: A Literature Review](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED446915) by Elizabeth F. Valentine,
- [Boys' And Girls' Brains Are Different: Gender Differences In Language Appear Biological](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/03/080303120346.htm) (ScienceDaily, 2008),
- [Girls lead boys in academic achievement globally](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/01/150126125015.htm) (ScienceDaily, January 2015),
- [Different neural strategies for junior high school male and female English learners](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/03/180323084822.htm) (ScienceDaily, March 2018),
- [Gender Differences in Acceptability and Usability of Computer Based Learning Package in Electrical and Electronics Technology in Nigeria](http://pubs.sciepub.com/education/1/10/2/index.html) by Bamidele Michael Efuwape1 and Ayotola Aremu (2013).

Given that gender differences appear to affect so many areas related to learning, I was wondering whether research has shown gender-based differences in [language learning strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_learning_strategies), and, if yes, what these differences are. Note that strategies are not the same thing as learning styles.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is some research that has addressed this issue.  Rebecca Oxford has done a lot of research on language learning strategies, and several of her studies addressed this issue.

[Oxford and Nyikos (1989)(behind paywall)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-4781.1989.tb06367.x) found that "sex had a profound effect on strategy choice"; Oxford identified 5 types of strategies, and of these 5, females used "formal rule-related practice strategies", "general study strategies" and "conversational input elicitation strategies" more than males.  No significant difference was found for "functional practice strategies" or "resourceful, independent strategies".

[Ehrman and Oxford (1989)(behind paywall)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-4781.1989.tb05302.x) also examine the relationship between gender and language strategy use.

[Green and Oxford (1995)](http://tesol.aua.am/tqd_2000/tqd_2000/Tq_d2000/VOL_29_2.PDF#page=36) looked at 50 strategies and found that 14 of these were used significantly more by women (including "Review English lessons often", "Skim then read carefully"; see table 5 in the article for all), and 1 was used signifcantly more by men ("Watch TV or movies in English").